# How to get a server name and port with HttpServletRequest usage without passing this as argument

Tags: java, url, servlets, request

today I met with an interesting problem. I want to conduct a user registration process with a unique link.

My registration link is built with serverName, serverPort and contextPath parameters. I need these three parameters with randomly generated UUID to create a unique URL, which will be responsible for user registration. Currently I am passing HttpServletRequest as a param in the controller method and after all, I started to wonder if this is a good practice to conduct URL generating on the controller side.

UserSevice:

```
    public void register(User user, String appUrl) {
        user.setStatus(UserStatus.INACTIVE);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(RoleType.ROLE_USER)));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        verificationTokenService.sendConfirmationEmail(user, appUrl);

    }
```

UserController:

```
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ResponseEntity registerUserAccount(
            @RequestBody @Valid User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" +
                request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
        userService.register(user, appUrl);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

I know that I can create a helper method like:

```
public String getServerName(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getServerName();
  }

public int getServerPort(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getServerPort();
  }

  public String getContextPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getContextPath();
  }
```

to get this parameter but still, I need to pass HttpServletRequest as a parameter and this is a problem due to the fact that this is an interface.

```
    String appUrl =
        "http://"
            + getServerName('this method require HttpServletRequest').getServerName()
            + ":"
            + getServerPort('this method require HttpServletRequest').getServerPort()
            + getContextPath('this method require HttpServletRequest').getContextPath();
```

Current solution works but I am interested in if there is another option to get these three parameters without passing HttpServletRequest as an argument on the controller side and avoid generating URL there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, this is usually done by having the base registration URL as a configuration parameter (e.g. in some `.properties` file, or in DB), because even if you have your `request` object, you cannot be sure the server name, port and contextPath are exactly what the user sees / uses to access your application. You have to consider your webapp can run behind some proxy/loadbalancer like Nginx or Apache HTTPD.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Ok, everything is clear so far, but is there another option to conduct above operation without adding extra proxy? Anyway, this application will not be available for public usage.